# Export Socket.io module to be available globally.

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Ok So I have some requirements, I would like to be able to use Socket.IO anywhere throughout my server, specifically within the routes to send out events when any CRUD operations have been performed.

The following is a file named sockets.js which I am using to initialize my sockets.

```
(function IIFE() {
  2   'use strict';
  3
  4   var socketIO = require('socket.io');
  5
  6   exports.initialize = function (server) {
  7     var io = socketIO.listen(server)
  8
  9     io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
 10       console.log(socket)
 11       console.log("Connected");
 12
 13       io.sockets.on('disconnect', (socket) => {
 14         console.log('Disconnect')
 15       });
 16     });
 17   }
 18
 19 })();
```

The following is my app.js which is essentially my server.

```
    2 (function IIFE() {
    3   'use strict';
    4
    5   const chalk = require('chalk');
    6
    7   if(!process.env.NODE_ENV) {
    8     console.log(chalk.red('No environment specified...') + chalk.blue('defaulting to \'development\''));
    9     process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
   10   }
   11
   12   const express = require('express');
   13   const mongoose = require('mongoose');
   14
   15   const config = require('./config/environment');
   16
   17   mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri, config.mongo.options);
   18
   19   mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
   20     console.error('Mongo Error: ' + err);
   21   });
   22
   23   const app = express();
   24   const server = require('http').createServer(app);
   25
+  26   var io = require('./sockets.js');
+  27   io.initialize(server);
+  28
   29   require('./config/express')(app);
   30   require('./routes')(app);
   31
   32   server.listen(config.port, config.ip, function() {
   33     console.log('order-api listening on %d in %s mode', config.port, app.get('env'));
   34   });
   35
   36   exports = module.exports = app;
   37 })();
```

The following file is in another folder called api. The entire application is a functioning application I am trying to integrate sockets into. However I cannot seem to understand how to Integrate sockets from my sockets.js and use them in the following route handlers.

```
(function IIFE() {
  2   'use strict';
  3
  4   const router = require('express').Router();
  5
  6   router.use('/carts', require('./cart'));
  7   router.use('/orders', require('./order'));
  8   router.use('/reports', require('./report'));
  9   router.use('/validators', require('./validator'));
 10
 11   module.exports = router;
 12 })();
```

Comment: There is zero reason to wrap your modules inside an IIFE.  They are already wrapped inside a function scope for you automatically by node.js.  No need to create another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare the variable `io` inside the `global` object so that it is visible from everywhere.

`global.io = socketIO.listen(server)`

Answer (score 0):

We can export socket module in our other files also.

```
let io;
const connectedUsers = [];
const setupSocketIO = function (server) {
  io = require('socket.io')(server, { cors: { origin: '*' } });
  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    connectedUsers[connectedUsers.length] = socket.id;
    socket.on('getConnectedUsers', () => {
      io.sockets.emit('returnConnectedUsers', connectedUsers.length);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      let socketIdToRemoveIndex = -1;
      for (let i = 0; i < connectedUsers.length; i++) {
        if (connectedUsers[i] === socket.id) {
          socketIdToRemoveIndex = i;
        }
      }
      if (socketIdToRemoveIndex !== -1) {
        connectedUsers.splice(socketIdToRemoveIndex, 1);
      }
      io.sockets.emit('connectedUsers', connectedUsers.length);
    });
  });
};
const Socket = function () {
  return {
    emit: function (event, data) {
      io.sockets.emit(event, data);
    },
    to: function (roomId, event, data) {
      io.sockets.to(roomId).emit(event, data);
    },
  };
};
exports.setupSocketIO = setupSocketIO;
exports.Socket = Socket;
```